# Как в tinyMce включить возможность добавления классов к изображению

Tags: tinymce

Собственно весь вопрос в названии
В загруженном тексте редактора, присутствует картинка,
при вызове контекстного меню или при нажатии на иконку картинки редактора 
появляется меню "вставить редактировать изображение"
Так вот, здесь отсутствует вкладка, в которой можно добавить класс изображению.
Как ее добавить? На офф сайте не нашел :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если кому еще нужно, то вот [документация](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_class_list) по добавлению классов.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "image",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "image",
  image_class_list: [
    {title: 'Нет', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
  ]
});
```

[image: Пример окна где есть выбор класса для картинки]

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Вопрос ТС - Как?, а не где найти документацию.

Comment: @0xdb ТС написал что не смог найти на офф сайте и я привел ссылку на официальную документацию где есть пример. Если вы хотите то я могу специально для вас продублировать пример кода.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: "image",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "image",
  image_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
  ]
});```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавте пример кода кнопкой править прямо в вопрос. Это будет интересно другим участникам сообщества, у которых возникнет похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен
если кому надо
В параметры инициализации добавить строчку

```
image_advtab: true,
```

Comment: похоже я поспешил, тут не класс добавляется, а прописываются стили...